# Isolate data frames from a spreadsheet to create a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How do I isolate data frames in R from a large spreadsheet of data and create a list from the isolated dataframes?

For example, my data of apple sales sold by different Groups in different states is in this format:

```
> data
1                    NSW   VIC   QLD
2 Group1       2013  500   501   985     
3              2014  601   520   999
4              2015  410   435   894
5 Group2       2013  508   501   806     
6              2014  694   780   899
7 Group3       2013  305   501   985     
8              2014  122   440   704
9              2015  210   235   523
```

I want all the data for Group1 (rows 2 to 4) to be dataframe1,
data from Group2 (rows 5 to 6) to be dataframe2,
data from Group3 (rows 7 to 9) to be dataframe3, etc.

Then I make a list:

```
data.list <- list(dataframe1,dataframe2,dataframe3, ....)
```

Since each data frame may differ in the number of rows, I can't do a loop that makes a data frame for every x number of rows. What would be the best approach to separate the original dataset into individual data frames based on the first column containing 'Group' affiliation?

I want to create a list that looks like this:

```
> data.list
[[Group1]]
                     NSW   VIC   QLD
1              2013  500   501   985     
2              2014  601   520   999
3              2015  410   435   894

[[Group2]]
                     NSW   VIC   QLD
1              2013  508   501   806     
2              2014  694   780   899

[[Group3]]
                     NSW   VIC   QLD
1              2013  305   501   985     
2              2014  122   440   704
3              2015  210   235   523
```

- Note: This is just dummy data, feel free to read in whatever data that is easiest to write code for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
                                         1L), .Label = c("", "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), class = "factor"), 
                     year = c(2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2013L, 2014L, 2013L, 2014L, 
                              2015L), NSW = c(500L, 601L, 410L, 508L, 694L, 305L, 122L, 
                                              210L), VIC = c(501L, 520L, 435L, 501L, 780L, 501L, 440L, 
                                                             235L), QLD = c(985L, 999L, 894L, 806L, 899L, 985L, 704L, 
                                                                            523L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df_list <- split(df, as.factor(df$group))
```

split will help you to create various list from groups  using baseR

Comment: Thanks! I find the `split` command works once I fill the rest of the columns with their group association first: `df[df==""] <- NA` then `df<-df %>% fill(group)`.